# Deduction of result type of callable

Tags: c++, c++14, callable, type-deduction

I try to deduce the type of callable template parameter, unfortunately without success:

```
template<typename callable, typename T_out >
class A
{};

template<typename callable>
auto make_A( callable f )
{
  return A<callable, typename std::result_of_t<callable> >{ f };
}

int main()
{
  make_A( []( float f ){ return f;} );
}
```

The code above causes the following error:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::__1::result_of<(lambda at /Users/arirasch/WWU/dev/xcode/tests/tests/main.cpp:31:11)>'
template <class _Tp> using result_of_t = typename result_of<_Tp>::type;
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `result_of_t<callable()>`? Although you'd need argument types for `result_of` to work.

Comment: `std::result_of_t<callable&(float)>`

Comment: Another error is that A's constructor does not take any arguments, whereas in make_A it takes f as an argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the argument list to `std::result_of`, otherwise it's impossible to tell the return type (`operator()` can be overloaded, after all).

```
return A<callable, std::result_of_t<callable(float)> >{ f }
```

(provided `A<callable, std::result_of_t<callable(float)>` can be constructed with `f`, which isn't the case for the example)

Comment: It won't work anyway. The OP forgot to provide a proper constructor for `A`.